# Trouble reading piped output in C

Tags: c, unix

I have 2 programs that I want the output of 1 to be the input of the other.
Like this:

```
user@local:~/work/example$ ./feeder | parser
```

My first program looks like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    const char *buff[] = {
        "$GPRMC,173843,A,3349.896,N,11808.521,W,000.0,360.0,230108,013.4,E*69\r\n",
        "$GPGGA,111609.14,5001.27,N,3613.06,E,3,08,0.0,10.2,M,0.0,M,0.0,0000*70\r\n",
        "$GPGSV,2,1,08,01,05,005,80,02,05,050,80,03,05,095,80,04,05,140,80*7f\r\n",
        "$GPGSV,2,2,08,05,05,185,80,06,05,230,80,07,05,275,80,08,05,320,80*71\r\n",
        "$GPGSA,A,3,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,00,00,00,00,0.0,0.0,0.0*3a\r\n",
        "$GPRMC,111609.14,A,5001.27,N,3613.06,E,11.2,0.0,261206,0.0,E*50\r\n",
        "$GPVTG,217.5,T,208.8,M,000.00,N,000.01,K*4C\r\n"
    };

   int it;

    for(it = 0; it < 6; ++it)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, buff[it]);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I type

```
user@local:~/work/example$ ./feeder | grep $
```

I do see that the output comes out every second.

On my parser program I have the following:

```
int main()
{
   while (1)
   {
       check_input()
   }
}

void check_input
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;
    int n;
    char buff[MAX_BUFF];
    int descriptor=0;

    /* Watch cb to see when it has input. */
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(descriptor, &rfds);

    /* Wait up to five seconds. */
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    retval = select(descriptor + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    /* Don't rely on the value of tv now! */

    if (retval == -1)
    {
        perror("select()");
    }
    else if (retval)
    {
//        printf("Data is available now.\n");
        if (FD_ISSET(0, &rfds))
        {
            n = read(0, buff, MAX_BUFF - 1);
            ... 
        }
    }
    else
        printf("No data within five seconds.\n");
```

}

The problem is that I have timeouts on my parser program. Nothing seems to be read. 
Any suggestion ?

EDIT 1:
The value of descriptor is 0, e.g. the value of STDIN_FILENO

Comment: First off, you should **not** use a non-literal string as the format argument to `fprintf`. Second, where is `descriptor` declared? You could/should just use `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: `descriptor` is probably for something else (writing). But you're right that the problem seem to be that `STDIN_FILENO` isn't added to the fd set.

Comment: Given that you're using `descriptor` in `FD_SET` and `select`, you should also be using `descriptor` in `FD_ISSET` and `read`.  Then it's just a matter of making sure that `descriptor` is initialized properly, as discussed in the previous comments.

Comment: In my code I'm actually using 0 for the descriptor value.

Comment: I've updated my code to actually use STDIN_FILENO and it's now working properly.
Only small glitch is that when the feeder executable stops, and probably the pipe breaks, my select constantly returns as if data was received. Probably I need to add some protection there.